# Different behavior when declaration type is different(Set vs TreeSet)

Tags: scala, for-loop

```
    var set = TreeSet(5,4,3,2,1)
    println(set)

    val diffSet: TreeSet[Int] = set
    // if I change above code to val diffSet: Set[Int] = set
    // the result is unsorted set.

    for (i <- diffSet; x = i) {
        println(i)
    }
    println("-" * 20)
    // the above code translates to below and print the same result
    val temp = diffSet.map(i => (i, i))
    for ((i, x) <- temp) {
        println(i)
    }
```

My question is if I defined a method like this:

```
def genSet:Set[Int] = {
  TreeSet(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
}
```

and when i want to use a for loop with it

```
for (i <- genSet; x = i + 1) {
  println(x)
}
```

the result is unsorted, how to fix this behavior without change the `genSet`'s return type. if I use for loop like below, it will be fine, but I hope to keep the above code style.

```
for (i <- genSet) {
  val x = i + 1
  println(x)
}
```

Comment: This may be a question for the mailing list: scala-user@listes.epfl.ch

Comment: I think it is a flaw to rely on the fact that the instantiated object happens to be a `TreeSet`. If you need ordering, then you want the static type to convey that the set will be sorted. If you'd notice that a function `def f:Set[T]` from a 3rd party lib happened to return `TreeSet[T]`, I'm sure you'd be reluctant to rely on this in your code as it would break if the library designer decided to change the instantiated type. Probably good idea to exercise the same discipline when calling your own code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Why the `map` version winds up unsorted

The `map` method (called with a function that we'll call `func`) takes an implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter that takes into account the type of the collection that `map` is being called on, in addition to the type that `func` returns to choose an appropriate return type. This is used to make `Map.map[Int]` or `BitSet.map[String]` do the right thing (return general purpose lists) while `Map.map[(String,Int)]` or `BitSet.map[Int]` also do the right thing (return a `Map` and a `BitSet`) respectively.

The `CanBuildFrom` is chosen at compile time, so it must be chosen based on the *static* type of the set that you call `map` on (the type the compiler knows about at compile time). The static type of `set` is `TreeSet`, but the static type of `diffset` is `Set`. The *dynamic* type of both (at runtime) is `TreeSet`.

When you call `map` on `set` (a `TreeSet`), the compiler chooses `immutable.this.SortedSet.canBuildFrom[Int](math.this.Ordering.Int)` as the `CanBuildFrom`.

When you call `map` on `diffset` (a `Set`), the compiler chooses `immutable.this.Set.canBuildFrom[Int]` as the `CanBuildFrom`.

## Why the `for` version winds up unsorted

The loop

```
for (i <- genSet; x = i + 1) {
  println(x)
}
```

desugars into

```
genSet.map(((i) => {
              val x = i.$plus(1);
              scala.Tuple2(i, x)
            })).foreach(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
              case scala.Tuple2((i @ _), (x @ _)) => println(x)
            }))
```

The desugared version includes a `map` function which will use the unsorted `CanBuildFrom` as I explained above.

On the other hand, the loop

```
for (i <- genSet) {
  val x = i + 1
  println(x)
}
```

desugars into

```
genSet.foreach(((i) => {
              val x = i.$plus(1);
              println(x)
            }))
```

Which doesn't use a `CanBuildFrom` at all, since no new collection is being returned.

Comment: Very interesting. Looks to me that the behavior of this method is therefore dependent upon the type of the variable to which it is assigned and implicits are the the means by which that happens. Arguably this is simply a drawback to the design of the API, but this behavior is unexpected.

Comment: @sblundy: What would you expect the order of the numbers in `SortedSet(1,2,3).map(x => 10-x)` to be? Note that the compiler doesn't know enough about the transformation function to make `SortedSet(7,6,5)` be an option. What about `SortedSet(2,3,4,5).map(x => x/2)` (which uses integer division)?

Comment: @sblundy: Depending on what he's trying to do with the order of the elements in the `SortedSet`, he actually want to call `toSeq` before calling map (if the point is traversing the mapped values in an order corresponding to their order in the set), or he may want to call `toSortedSet` (if the point is range lookup of the mapped values). The appropriate behavior relates entirely to how he plans to use the orderedness.

Comment: Very good explain for this situation, I vague feel `map` cause the problem, but didn't know how, and I know it now.

Comment: Whoops: there is no `toSortedSet`, however one can use `TreeSet.empty ++ diffSet` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 6):

`Set` does not guarantee ordering. Even if the underlying class is a `TreeSet`, if the expected result is a `Set` you'll loose the ordering in the first transformation you do.

If you want ordering, do not use `Set`. I suggest, say, `SortedSet`.

Comment: Doesn't that violate polymorphism? One uses the interface to guarantee what happens but the behavior of the instance should not vary by the context in which it is used.

Comment: @sblundy: there are different kinds of polymorphism. Inheritance and function overriding are one kind of polymorphism. Generics are another kind of polymorphism. It's the latter kind that's causing problems.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Based on your answer, the problem appears to be implicits. They enable the method to change its behavior based upon its context. Sometimes this is a feature, sometimes not.

Comment: @sblundy: That's correct. It's implicits. I made a stupid brain fart in my last comment.

Comment: @sblundy Not, it doesn't violate polymorphism -- this is determined by the type parameters. Specifically, `Set` extends `SetLike[A, Set[A]]`, and it is the second parameter of `SetLike` that determine the _lower bound_ of the type returned by `map` and similar methods. A `SortedSet` extends, indirectly, `SetLike[A, This]`, where `This` is defined as `SortedSet[A]`, which lowers the bound. The final step of jumping from the type bound to the result type is done through implicit.

Comment: @sblundy One thing to note is that `map` & cia do not produce a new collection using their own constructor. They use a constructor passed implicitly as a parameter -- the infamous `CanBuildFrom`. This is what makes it possible for `BitSet` to exist and be a `Set` supporting a method like `map` -- which may produce results impossible to represent in a `BitSet`. Anyway, the `Set` produced by `map` is a _new_ `Set`. The old `Set`, a `TreeSet`, still iterates in sorting order, which is all the guarantee it has.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: On one level, you're right. This would appear to be how it was designed. The other way to look at it is that is violates the principle of not surprising the user.

Comment: @sblundy It surprises me that the user expects a `Set` to produce new sets that preserve characteristics of the implementation of `Set` -- that's a violation of encapsulation.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral Why does the `CanBuildFrom` returned from `SetFactory.setCanBuildFrom` implements `def apply(from: CC[_])` as `newBuilder[A]` instead of `from.newBuilder[A]`? It seems that this would take care of the problem, no? That's how it's implemented in `TraversableFactory`.

Comment: OK, I found out it wouldn't — SortedSet builders take an implicit ordering, and we can't reuse the one of the original Set as the type being mapped to may differ.

Answer (score 2):

Change the sig of `genSet` to return a `SortedSet`

```
def genSet:SortedSet[Int] = {
  TreeSet(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
}
```

This is probably some sort of bug. I would have expected your code to work too.

I think `map` is the culprit. This results in the same behavior:

```
for (i <- genSet.map(_ + 1)) { println(i) }
```

And `for(i <- genSet; x = i + 1)` equates to `for(x <- genSet.map({i => i + 1}))`

Comment: The "wrong" map is being called: scala> TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(identity)                
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)

scala> (TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5): Set[Int]).map(identity)    
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Looks that way to me. The big refactoring binge for 2.8 was supposed to reduce problems like this...

Comment: The big refactoring binge for 2.8 was supposed to solve **other** much more common problems (see my answer to this question) by introducing a `CanBuildFrom` to decide what type a call to `map` should return. The introduction of the `CanBuildFrom` created the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
scala> for (i <-genSet.view; x = i + 1) println(x)
2
3
4
5
6
```

Although, it's the type of trick that when you look at it after a few months, you may wonder why you added `.view` ...

Comment: And it isn't really guaranteed to work -- at least until the tickets opened on it get solved. :-)

Comment: You mean 4116 and 4117? Yeah I had skipped over that thread and wasn't aware of it.