# How can I ensure that the dynamic type of my custom Scala collection is preserved during a map()?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-collections, static-typing

I read the very interesting [article on the architecture of the Scala 2.8 collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html) and I've been experimenting with it a little bit. For a start, I simply copied the final code for the nice `RNA` example. Here it is for reference:

```
abstract class Base
case object A extends Base
case object T extends Base
case object G extends Base
case object U extends Base

object Base {
  val fromInt: Int => Base = Array(A, T, G, U)
  val toInt: Base => Int = Map(A -> 0, T -> 1, G -> 2, U -> 3)
}

final class RNA private (val groups: Array[Int], val length: Int)
    extends IndexedSeq[Base] with IndexedSeqLike[Base, RNA] {

  import RNA._

  // Mandatory re-implementation of `newBuilder` in `IndexedSeq`
  override protected[this] def newBuilder: Builder[Base, RNA] =
    RNA.newBuilder

  // Mandatory implementation of `apply` in `IndexedSeq`
  def apply(idx: Int): Base = {
    if (idx < 0 || length <= idx)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    Base.fromInt(groups(idx / N) >> (idx % N * S) & M)
  }

  // Optional re-implementation of foreach, 
  // to make it more efficient.
  override def foreach[U](f: Base => U): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    var b = 0
    while (i < length) {
      b = if (i % N == 0) groups(i / N) else b >>> S
      f(Base.fromInt(b & M))
      i += 1
    }
  }
}

object RNA {

  private val S = 2 // number of bits in group
  private val M = (1 << S) - 1 // bitmask to isolate a group
  private val N = 32 / S // number of groups in an Int

  def fromSeq(buf: Seq[Base]): RNA = {
    val groups = new Array[Int]((buf.length + N - 1) / N)
    for (i <- 0 until buf.length)
      groups(i / N) |= Base.toInt(buf(i)) << (i % N * S)
    new RNA(groups, buf.length)
  }

  def apply(bases: Base*) = fromSeq(bases)

  def newBuilder: Builder[Base, RNA] =
    new ArrayBuffer mapResult fromSeq

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[RNA, Base, RNA] =
    new CanBuildFrom[RNA, Base, RNA] {
      def apply(): Builder[Base, RNA] = newBuilder
      def apply(from: RNA): Builder[Base, RNA] = newBuilder
    }
}
```

Now, here's my problem. If I run this, everything's fine:

```
val rna = RNA(A, G, T, U)
println(rna.map(e => e)) // prints RNA(A, G, T, U)
```

but this code transforms the RNA to a Vector!

```
val rna: IndexedSeq[Base] = RNA(A, G, T, U)
println(rna.map(e => e)) // prints Vector(A, G, T, U)
```

This is a problem, as client code unaware of the `RNA` class may transform it back to a `Vector` instead when only mapping from `Base` to `Base`. Why is that so, and what are the ways to fix it?

P.-S.: I've found a tentative answer (see below), please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's may be a stupid idea, but... Why you do not override companion as it done in the IndexedSeq?

Comment: `companion` must return a `GenericCompanion[IndexedSeq]`. If the `RNA` object implements it, then it must define `def newBuilder: Builder[A,IndexedSeq[A]]`, which is more general than the builder we want to provide, so we can't do like this.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563484/different-behavior-when-declaration-type-is-differentset-vs-treeset/4564811#4564811. I also think it's not a good idea for the client code to explicitly type to `IndexedSeq[Base]` but then expect RNA behavior. Why not do `val rna = RNA(A, G, T, U)`?

Comment: @huynhjl Why not? As a subclass of IndexedSeq[Base], RNA is able to do everything IndexedSeq[Base] does, as per the Liskov substitution principle. Sometimes, all you know is that it's an IndexedSeq, and you still expect filter, map and friends to keep the same specific implementation. Actually, filter does it — but not map.

Comment: @JPP GenericCompanion is covariant against collection class. So theoretically it's possible to provide custom companion of type GenericCompanion[RNA] and it should be accepted by the collection library. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CheatEx Yes, you're missing the fact that the parameter of `GenericCompanion` is a type constructor with one type argument, like `IndexedSeq`, and `RNA` is not a type constructor, so it won't fit here. That's why it is named *Generic*Companion: because it must accept any kind of element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the static type of the `rna` variable is `IndexedSeq[Base]`, the automatically inserted `CanBuildFrom` cannot be the one defined in the `RNA` companion object, as the compiler is not supposed to know that `rna` is an instance of `RNA`.

So where does it come from? The compiler falls back on an instance of `GenericCanBuildFrom`, the one defined in the `IndexedSeq` object. `GenericCanBuildFrom`s produce their builders by calling `genericBuilder[B]` on the originating collection, and a requirement for that generic builder is that it can produce generic collections that can hold any type `B` — as of course, the return type of the function passed to a `map()` is not constrained.

In this case, `RNA` is only an `IndexedSeq[Base]` and not a generic `IndexedSeq`, so it's not possible to override `genericBuilder[B]` in `RNA` to return a `RNA`-specific builder — we would have to check at runtime whether `B` is `Base` or something else, but we cannot do that.

I think this explains *why*, in the question, we get a `Vector` back. As to how we can fix it, it's an open question…

**Edit**: Fixing this requires `map()` to know whether it's mapping to a subtype of `A` or not. A significant change in the collections library would be needed for this to happen. See the related question [Should Scala's map() behave differently when mapping to the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678682/should-scalas-map-behave-differently-when-mapping-to-the-same-type).

Answer (score 1):

On why I think it's not a good idea to statically type to a weaker type than RNA. It should really be a comment (cause it's more an opinion but that would be harder to read). From your comment to my comment:

> *Why not? As a subclass of IndexedSeq[Base], RNA is able to do everything IndexedSeq[Base] does, as per the Liskov substitution principle. Sometimes, all you know is that it's an IndexedSeq, and you still expect filter, map and friends to keep the same specific implementation. Actually, filter does it — but not map*

`filter` does it because the compiler can statically guarantee it. If you keep elements from a particular collection, you end up with a collection from the same type. `map` cannot guarantee that, it depends on the function that is passed.

My point is more on the act of *specifying explicitly a type and expecting more than what it can deliver*. As a user of the RNA collection, I may write code that depends on certain properties of this collection such as efficient memory representation.

So let's assume I state in `val rna: IndexedSeq[Base]` that `rna` is *just* an `IndexedSeq`. A few lines later I call a method `doSomething(rna)` where I expect the efficient memory representation, what would be the best signature for that? `def doSomething[T](rna: IndexedSeq[Base]): T` or `def doSomething[T](rna: RNA): T`?

I think it should be the latter. But if that's the case, then the code won't compile because `rna` is not statically an `RNA` object. If the method signature should be the former, then in essence I'm saying that I don't care about the memory representation efficiency. So I think the act of specifying a weaker type explicitly but expecting a stronger behavior is a contradiction. Which is what you do in your example.

Now I do see that even if I did:

```
val rna = RNA(A, G, T, U)
val rna2 = doSomething(rna)
```

where somebody else wrote:

```
def doSomething[U](seq: IndexedSeq[U]) = seq.map(identity)
```

I would like to have `rna2` be a `RNA` object but that won't happen... It means that this somebody else should write a method that takes a `CanBuildFrom` if they want to have callers get more specific types:

```
def doSomething[U, To](seq: IndexedSeq[U])
   (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[U], U, To]) = seq.map(identity)(cbf)
```

Then I could call: `val rna2: RNA = doSomething(rna)(collection.breakOut)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I mostly agree. I just find that it's a pity that in this particular case, the consistency that was present in other parts of the collections library breaks down. It is really impossible for `map` to be defined in a way where we could preserve the same type of collection just like a filter? Maybe something like `def smarterMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit sameTypeEv: A =:= B = null)`, where `sameTypeEv` is not null if we're mapping to the same type?… Just thinking out loud…

Comment: Or rather: `(implicit canUseCalleeBuilderEvidence: B <:< A = null)`, as even a non-variant collection of As could contain only Bs, if `B <: A`.