# Should Scala's map() behave differently when mapping to the same type?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-collections, implicit, static-typing

In the Scala Collections framework, I think there are some behaviors that are counterintuitive when using `map()`.

We can distinguish two kinds of transformations on (immutable) collections. Those whose implementation calls `newBuilder` to recreate the resulting collection, and those who go though an implicit `CanBuildFrom` to obtain the builder.

The first category contains all transformations where the type of the contained elements does not change. They are, for example, `filter`, `partition`, `drop`, `take`, `span`, etc. These transformations are free to call `newBuilder` and to recreate the same collection type as the one they are called on, no matter how specific: filtering a `List[Int]` can always return a `List[Int]`; filtering a `BitSet` (or the `RNA` example structure described in [this article on the architecture of the collections framework](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html)) can always return another `BitSet` (or `RNA`). Let's call them the *filtering transformations*.

The second category of transformations need `CanBuildFrom`s to be more flexible, as the type of the contained elements may change, and as a result of this, the type of the collection itself maybe cannot be reused: a `BitSet` cannot contain `String`s; an `RNA` contains only `Base`s. Examples of such transformations are `map`, `flatMap`, `collect`, `scanLeft`, `++`, etc. Let's call them the *mapping transformations*.

Now here's the main issue to discuss. No matter what the static type of the collection is, all filtering transformations will return the same collection type, while the collection type returned by a mapping operation can vary depending on the static type.

```
scala> import collection.immutable.TreeSet
import collection.immutable.TreeSet

scala> val treeset = TreeSet(1,2,3,4,5) // static type == dynamic type
treeset: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val set: Set[Int] = TreeSet(1,2,3,4,5) // static type != dynamic type
set: Set[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> treeset.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(2, 4) // fine, a TreeSet again

scala> set.filter(_ % 2 == 0)    
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = TreeSet(2, 4) // fine

scala> treeset.map(_ + 1)        
res2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) // still fine

scala> set.map(_ + 1)    
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(4, 5, 6, 2, 3) // uh?!
```

Now, I understand why this works like this. It is explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660656/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-dynamic-type-of-my-custom-scala-collection-is-preserved) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563484/different-behavior-when-declaration-type-is-differentset-vs-treeset/4564811#4564811). In short: the implicit `CanBuildFrom` is inserted based on the static type, and, depending on the implementation of its `def apply(from: Coll)` method, may or may not be able to recreate the same collection type.

Now my only point is, when we know that we are using a mapping operation yielding a collection with the **same element type** (which the compiler can statically determine), we could mimic the way the filtering transformations work and use the collection's native builder. We can reuse `BitSet` when mapping to `Int`s, create a new `TreeSet` with the same ordering, etc.

Then we would avoid cases where

```
for (i <- set) {
  val x = i + 1
  println(x)
}
```

does not print the incremented elements of the `TreeSet` in the same order as

```
for (i <- set; x = i + 1)
  println(x)
```

So:

- Do you think this would be a good idea to change the behavior of the mapping transformations as described?
- What are the inevitable caveats I have grossly overlooked?
- How could it be implemented?

I was thinking about something like an `implicit sameTypeEvidence: A =:= B` parameter, maybe with a default value of `null` (or rather an `implicit canReuseCalleeBuilderEvidence: B <:< A = null`), which could be used at runtime to give more information to the `CanBuildFrom`, which in turn could be used to determine the type of builder to return.

Comment: True that your two examples of `for( i <- set ... )` are confusing, and I didn't quite follow from where that comes from. But generally, if you are relying on a sorted set, make sure your (known) type is a sorted set. I don't see why if at some point you assign a `TreeSet` to a `val set: Set[...]` you could possible want that set to behave like a sorted set. An assignment like `val set: Set[...] = ...` clearly says to me that you are expecting a set without any implications about the set order. If you want a sorted set, request it. So I don't really see your use case here.

Comment: `Set` vs `SortedSet` is just an instance of the more general problem. Suppose, as in the example of the article I link, that you hand out your instance of `RNA` to some general lib that only knows `IndexedSeq[Base]` does does a `map()` on it. You'll only get back a `Vector[Base]` and not an `RNA`. More generally speaking, it would be nice if the returned collection is as specific as it can be, consistently with `filter`, etc.

Comment: Plus, as a library designer, you might not rely on a `SortedSet`, but your clients may. I'd hate to have to write `processSortedSet[E](xs: SortedSet[E])` in addition to `processSet[E](xs: Set[E])`. Wouldn't you?

Comment: And why not something around `processSet[E, S <: Set[E]](xs: S) : S` (look for the pimp-my-library questions that involve collections to find the signatures needed to pass in and out any collection type)

Comment: Actually, the required signature would be something like `processSet[E, S <: Set[E]](xs: S)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S, E, S]): S`. Yes, this would work, but then we just have to hope that every library designer will think of this problem and implement this solution, instead of fixing it once and for all in the collections library.

Comment: The idea of a *sameTypeEvidence* is interesting but it won't make the API simpler. The implication of changing the standard libraries cannot be taken lightly. Sometimes some changes improving things in one part could have adverse effects in some other situations. You could try the idea in your own code with a pimp pattern and if you feel that's successful reach out to the mailing list.

Comment: How can I use a pimp if my function has the same signature (without the implicits) as Traversable#map?

Comment: Although I agree that the method's signature gets more complicated, the actual use of map will not change, and the API docs, which show the *use case signature* of the methods, wouldn't change either. I have never seen a use case where clients would actually pass an instance of `A =:= B`, `A <:< B`, or `A <%< B`.

Answer (score 1):

I looked again at it, and I think your problem doesn't arise from a particular deficiency of Scala collections, but rather a missing builder for `TreeSet`. Because the following does work as intended:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val seq1: Seq[Int] = list
seq1.map( _ + 1 ) // yields List

val vector = Vector(1,2,3,4,5)
val seq2: Seq[Int] = vector
seq2.map( _ + 1 ) // yields Vector
```

So the reason is that `TreeSet` is missing a specialised companion object/builder:

```
seq1.companion.newBuilder[Int]    // ListBuffer
seq2.companion.newBuilder[Int]    // VectorBuilder
treeset.companion.newBuilder[Int] // Set (oops!)
```

So my guess is, if you take proper provision for such a companion for your `RNA` class, you may find that both `map` and `filter` work as you wish...?

Comment: Thanks for investigating, Sciss! You can try the `RNA` example, it's linked there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660656/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-dynamic-type-of-my-custom-scala-collection-is-preserved and comes from Martin Odersky's article there: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html and it seems to me that nothing is missing. And indeed, the collections framework cannot do better than the current behavior unless `map()` knows that the transformation maps objects to the same type.

Comment: As for the `TreeSet` case: `TreeSet` does have a `TreeSet` builder, which requires an implicit `Ordering` parameter in its `newBuilder` method, thus `treeset.companion` cannot be `TreeSet` because `TreeSet.newBuilder` does not override `Set.newBuilder`. Again, we can only solve this if we know we're mapping to the same type.

Comment: There's a very similar problem over in the Haskell world: Sets and Maps can't implement the map function either because they can't enforce the Ord constraint.

Comment: I'm afraid Jean-Philippe is right. Or at least, that's the conclusion we reached here (for BitSet not TreeSet, but the considerations seem to me to be the same): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/dThOh07mZKo/VX8CeiWxAj4J